# Disable Celery Worker Startup Text

Tags: logging, celery, worker

How would you completely stop a Celery worker from printing any messages to stdout? I have tried

```
celery worker --app proj --logfile=/dev/null
```

This will stop all messages **EXCEPT** The following message that gets printed on startup:

```
 -------------- <version>
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- <OS>
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         <app>
- ** ---------- .> transport:   <QUEUE>
- ** ---------- .> results:     <DB>
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 10 <con>
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           <exchange>
```

Is there a way to stop this message from being printed on startup? I am using an upstart script.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify the why ?

Comment: This prints a message to the 'upstart/worker.log'. We want to keep that log clean for monitoring purposes. It should only contain errors that occur when starting up service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ditched `celery worker` in favor of `celery multi` a long time ago. One of the advantages of `multi` over `worker` is that it does not produce the output you are trying to get rid of. A typical output would be:

```
celery multi v3.1.23 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
        > foo@localhost: OK
```

You can even get rid of this bit of output if you want by using the `--quiet` option.

I tried quiet with `celery worker` just now but still got the undesirable output.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the reason why the redirect to dev/null of log file will not work for the startup message is explained by [this line](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/af7dfcd34eed874e393b85e686940fb3a2685dd4/celery/apps/worker.py#L145) in celery worker.py source.
As you can see the startup message is a print to stdout.

One way to overcome will be to create your own version of worker.py but I see it as to much pain for just remove few lines from a logfile.

I can't think of other way of solving your problem.